# Postgres: strange long request: A is fast, B is fast, A WHERE IN B is slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, where, query-performance

There is a lot of rows in table "logs" (the Request A FROM).

Request A is quick and Request B is quick.

Put together, Request A WHERE IN Request B is very long. Is that normal?

Request A is very quick:

```
--request A
SELECT "rid", max("createdAt") as "createdAt"
FROM "logs"
WHERE "rid" IN (17,71,196,187,111,86,108,81,54,184,245,27,118,100,175,136,130,67,45)
GROUP BY "rid";
```

Request B is very quick:

```
--request B
SELECT "dr"."rid"
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT "eid", "tid", count(*) over (partition by "eid", "tid") count, id as "rid"
    FROM rs
    WHERE "deletedAt" is NULL
  ) "nr"
WHERE count > 1
) "dr"
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = "dr"."tid"
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = teams."pid"
ORDER BY "eid", "tid"
```

The result of B is the same list of numbers than in request A WHERE IN.

Replacing request A WHERE IN by request B, it becomes very slow.

Postgres: 9.5.6

Query plan for Request A:
[image]

Query plan or Request B:
[image]

Query plan for Requast A WHEREIN B:
[image]

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put together, Request A WHERE IN Request B is very long. Is that
>   normal?

Yes, that's fairly common when elaborating queries. In the first case, the `IN(...)` clause has only a handful of constants. The planner knows exactly how many values and how frequent they are in the table, so it has a good chance to find an optimal execution plan (in this case, an index scan).

When the inside of this `IN (...)` clause is replaced by a subquery, the planner may mis-estimate the number of values that this subquery will produce, or their frequency, or both, especially if the subquery is complex, and so it may choose a non-optimal plan compared to when there is a list of constants inside `IN (...)`.

Comment: Ok, I was surprised because request B is fast, but Postgres didn't know that, that's it? It can't decide to run sub-query first.

Comment: @Slim: It could decide as you say, if its estimate of the number of results produced by B was accurate. It guesses it's going to be 11182 rows while in reality it's about 20. As an ad-hoc solution, you could rewrite the combined query with B in a WITH clause, and it would choose the fast plan.